# Java Netbeans DB tables relationship

Tags: java, database

I am trying to create a Java project using a database.

I have created a database with 3 tables and created a relationship connecting 2 of the tables to other. So `Members`, `Donation` and `Expenses`. `Donations` and `Expenses` are connected to `Members`. I used the following SQL to create the relationship:

```
ALTER TABLE <TABLE>
    ADD CONSTRAINT TABLE_FK
    FOREIGN KEY (MEMBER_ID)
    REFERENCES MEMBERS (ID);
```

When I try and add data to either the `Donations` or `Expenses` table I can't because of the connection with `Members` table: it has a variable `<MEMBERS member>` instead of `<String Member_ID>`. How do I add data to the tables or should I just recreate my database?

Comment: Inserts information in member first , then dependent tables. Or disable constraint and enable after insertions.

Comment: How is this related to java at all?  How are you trying to add data?  Is the column nullable?

Comment: Yeah, this database may be referenced by a Java program, but this is by no means a Java question.  You may want to replace the java tag with a mySQL tag (or whatever flavor of database you're using, since you didn't mention which in your question).

Comment: Are you trying to prepopulate data into your tables from a SQL client, or are you trying to use a Java program to insert data into your tables?  If it's the latter, then I'd suggest you post the offending Java code and phrase your question accordingly, in which case calling this a Java question would be justified (and we can provide a more useful answer).

Comment: @BrandonMcKenzie I am using a Java programme to insert the code.

Comment: Donations donAdd = new Donations();;

            donAdd.setAmount(200.00);
            donAdd.setAvailable(true);
            donAdd.setDonationDate("12/12/2000");
            donAdd.setDonationType("Type");
           
            donAdd.setRefNum(1);

Comment: Does Donations have a setMember method?  Use whatever framework you're using to interface with the database via POJOs to create Member or fetch and existing Member and populate the Donations member field with that.

Comment: @BrandonMcKenzie thnak you I will trythat

Comment: No problem.  I also broke that comment out into an answer since it's being taken as such.

Answer (score 0):

So, based on that posted snippet in the comments, you need to either create a new Member object, or retrieve an existing member object using whatever framework you are using to interface with your database via POJOs, assuming that Member is non-nullable in Donations, and use Donations (presumed) setMember method to populate the Member.